# TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' for python

Tags: python

I'm trying to setup a cron auto delete file on Deluge torrent client, code is as following:

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import logging
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta
from deluge.ui.client import client
import deluge.component as component
from deluge.log import LOG as log
from twisted.internet import reactor
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr, level=logging.DEBUG)

def printData(dresult):
    if dresult:
        print "Command executed with result: ", dresult
    else:
       sys.stderr.write(str(failure))

def on_connect_success(result):
    def on_get_torrent_value(value):
        for torrent in value:
             seedtime = datetime.fromtimestamp(value[torrent]["seeding_time"]) - datetime.fromtimestamp(0)
             if value[torrent]["label"] in labels and value[torrent]["is_finished"] == True and seedtime >= timedelta(hours = totalseedtime):
                   --- multiple of commands ---
        client.disconnect()
        reactor.stop()

    client.core.get_torrents_status({}, ["name", "is_finished", "save_path", "seeding_time", "label"]).addCallback(on_get_torrent_value)
    client.core.remove_torrent({}, remove_data = False).addCallbacks(printData)

d.addCallback(on_connect_success)

def on_connect_fail(result):
    print "result:", result

d.addErrback(on_connect_fail)

reactor.run()
```

When executed, the debug log returned:

```
DEBUG:deluge:ConfigManager started..
INFO:deluge:Connecting to daemon at 127.0.0.1:58846..
INFO:deluge:Connected to daemon at 127.0.0.1:58846..
ERROR:deluge:RPCError Message Received!
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RPCRequest: core.remove_torrent({}, remove_data=False)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge-1.3.11-py2.7.egg/deluge/core/rpcserver.py", line 299, in dispatch
    ret = self.factory.methods[method](*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge-1.3.11-py2.7.egg/deluge/core/core.py", line 326, in remove_torrent
    return self.torrentmanager.remove(torrent_id, remove_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge-1.3.11-py2.7.egg/deluge/core/torrentmanager.py", line 568, in remove
    torrent_name = self.torrents[torrent_id].get_status(["name"])["name"]

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unhandled error in Deferred:
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: deluge.ui.client.DelugeRPCError: <deluge.ui.client.DelugeRPCError object at 0x1aeae50>
INFO:deluge:Connection lost to daemon at 127.0.0.1:58846 reason: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.
```

I understand that the dic I pass to client.core.remove_torrent is something wrong in format, but dont know how to fix it. Any help in much appreciate! Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Google the error message. Why are you passing in `{}`?

Comment: [Here's the documentation on `remove_torrent`](http://deluge-torrent.org/docs/master/modules/core/torrentmanager.html#deluge.core.torrentmanager.TorrentManager.remove). Note the expected types of the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `dict` as a key (it's mutable - see the description of [frozenset](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) for an explanation).

It looks like you're supposed to pass some torrent_id to remove, and whatever this is, it must be something hashable - ie, not a `dict`.